# Price return or total return for GARCH models

Tags: time-series, returns, garch

Is there a problem in modeling total return rather than price return when using GARCH models?

My line of thinking is that total return includes dividends, which is only a "pseudo-random variable" in that it is much more predictable than price changes, which should only come from "news".

Does anyone know of any research or have any thoughts on this?